# Btrfs: Is there an easy way to find a file by block numbers it occupies?

Tags: btrfs

Say, you have filesystem *Btrfs* formatted, then you, all of the sudden as it happens, wonder — what files occupy blocks #356 and #789, how you gonna answer this question?

Comment: Can you add some background information: Why do you need to know? What is the situation?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor in my case I want to search for the file containing a give block because I'm getting `corrupt leaf: root=257 block=871612416 slot=159, unexpected item end, have 639006124 expect 7856` but `btrfs scrub` doesn't report any issues.

Comment: Please add improvements to question, by improving the question: don't expect people to read all the comments, before they know what you are attempting to do.

Comment: there're no requirements to explain to everyone why someone needs something to do, it's just your own quirks you'd better to have fixed with a psychologist